# Probability-generating function quadratic

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

We have random variables $X,X_1,X_2,I_1$ and $I_2$ which are independent, $X,X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same distribution and $I_1,I_2 \sim \text{Bernoulli}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$. The following holds $$X = 2+I_1X_1+I_2X_2.$$ We need to compute the probability-generating function os $X$.

So $I_1$ and $I_2$ are indicators and we have:

- $X \mid \{I_1 = 1, I_2 = 1\} \sim 2+X_1+X_2$  therefore $\mathbb{E}[s^X\mid I_1 = 1, I_2 = 1] = s^2M_X(s)^2$,
- $X \mid \{I_1 = 0, I_2 = 1\} \sim 2+X_2$  therefore $\mathbb{E}[s^X\mid I_1 = 0, I_2 = 1] = s^2M_X(s)$,
- $X \mid \{I_1 = 1, I_2 = 0\} \sim 2+X_1$  therefore $\mathbb{E}[s^X\mid I_1 = 1, I_2 = 0] = s^2M_X(s)$,
- $X \mid \{I_1 = 0, I_2 = 0\} \sim 2$  therefore $\mathbb{E}[s^X\mid I_1 = 0, I_2 = 0] = s^2$.

From there we get $$M_X(s)=\sum_{i,j\in\{0,1\}}\mathbb{E}[s^X\mid I_1 = i, I_2 = j]\cdot\mathbb{P}(I_1 = i, I_2 = j).$$
Because $I_1$ and $I_2$ are independent and $\sim \text{Bernoulli}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ we get $\mathbb{P}(I_1 = i, I_2 = j)=\frac{1}{4}$. We get the equation $$M_X(s) = \frac{s^2}{4}M_X(s)^2 + \frac{s^2}{2}M_X(s)+\frac{s^2}{4}$$ and from there $$\frac{s^2}{4}M_X(s)^2 + \left(\frac{s^2}{2}-1\right)M_X(s)+\frac{s^2}{4} = 0.$$ Solving the quadratic we get $$M_X(s)=\frac{2-s^2\pm\sqrt{1-s^2}}{s^2}.$$

So now my question; **which sign before the square root should I choose to get the PGF of $X$?**
(If I have made any mistakes, please correct me xD.)

Comment: Do you mean to obtain the probability generating function (not mgf), right?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry.

Comment: If the five random variables are mutually independent, they can't be related by $X = 2+I_1X_1+I_2X_2$.

Comment: Yeah, $X,X_1$ and $X_2$ which have the same distribution can't be related, thanks. But does it seem okay from then on?

Comment: the first bullet point shoud be $s^2M_{X_1}(s)^2$, the same for the rest; I hope this helps.

Comment: But if $X,X_1$ and $X_2$ are distributed equally, then doesn't $M_X(s)=M_{X_1}(s)=M_{X_2}(s)$.

Comment: My main question is just which sign to choose, in the formula for $M_X(s)$ at the end.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a distribution for $X, X_1, X_2$ to satisfy the above properties. The series expansions for both roots are
\begin{align*}
G_1(s) = \frac{2-s^2 + \sqrt{1-s^2}}{s^2} &= 3s^{-2} - \frac{3}{2}s^0 - \frac{1}{8}s^2 - \cdots \\
G_2(s) =\frac{2-s^2 - \sqrt{1-s^2}}{s^2} &= s^{-2} \color{red}{- \frac{1}{2}s^0} + \frac{1}{8}s^2 + \cdots
\end{align*}
For $G_1(s)$, all coeffients are not bounded between $[0, 1]$, and for $G_2(s)$, the coefficient of $s^0$ is negative.

In general, you verify if the resulting solutions satisfy the properties of a PGF; if multiple solutions satisfy, then you have non-unique distributions which satisfy your original property.